# Regex.IsMatch is not working when text including "$"

Tags: c#, winforms

Regex.IsMatch method returns the wrong result while checking the following condition,

```
string text = "$0.00";
Regex compareValue = new Regex(text);
bool result = compareValue.IsMatch(text);
```

The above code returns as **"False"**. Please let me know if i missed anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Regex` class has a special method for escaping characters in a pattern: [Regex.Escape()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx)

Change your code like this:

```
string text = "$0.00";
Regex compareValue = new Regex(Regex.Escape(text)); // Escape characters in text
bool result = compareValue.IsMatch(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

"$" is a special character in C# regex. Escape it first.

```
Regex compareValue = new Regex(@"\$0\.00");
bool result = compareValue.IsMatch("$0.00");
```

Regex expressions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have to *escape* `$` since it is a special (reserved) character which means "end of string". In case `.` means just dot (say, decimal separator) you have to escape it as well (when not escaped, `.` means "any symbol"):

```
string pattern = @"\$0\.00";

bool result = RegEx.IsMatch(text, pattern);
```

As for your original pattern, it has *no chance to match* any string, since   `$0.00` means

```
   $ end of string, followed by
   0 zero
   . any character
   0 zero
   0 zero
```

but *end of string* can't be followed by...

Comment: Thanks. How can i check the pattern in generic way? In my question, it is known value...Is there any easier way to check the pattern in generic way for any of the text?

Comment: @Neelakandan K: you may find useful https://regex101.com/ where you can test the patterns and have them explained.

Comment: Thanks. FYI. Regex.Escape method is the solution

Comment: @Neelakandan K: I know; but be careful with `Regex.Escape`: often you want *unescaped* `$` for the *end of string*, `.` for *any character*...

Answer (score 2):

Both '.' and '$' are special characters and thus you need to escape them if you want to match the character itself. '.' matches any character and '$' matches the end of a string

see: https://regex101.com/r/pK2uY6/1